# php if this then that AND that

Tags: php

Is there a way in php to write if $a equals 1 then $b is 2 and $c is 3?

```
if ($a == 1) $b=2 AND $c=3;
```

doesn't work. Or do I need to write all three of them separately?

Comment: if($a == 1)
{
  $b = 2;
  $c = 3;
}

Comment: Try making 2 lines of code each containing the code you want to execute. Use curly braces as well then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its very simple.

Comment: @Kris I know it's very simple and I can't believe that it didn't pop out of my brains, but there are people on this level who are helped by this answer. I don't think there is written in the rules that it should be very hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `AND` simply separate it with different statement

```
if ($a == 1) {$b=2; $c=3;}
```

Comment: Duhhhhhh. Terrible I had to ask this question. Sometimes my brain is locked. O well, nothing wrong with easy answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your have a syntax problem there. But it's possible :

```
if ($a == 1) {
    $b = 2;
    $c = 3;
}
```